# I am not able to switch Scene in Unity with Easy Movie Texture Plugin

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, textures, movie

I am trying to on gaze function from Google VR, and switch scene that will then play movie clip using Easy movie Texture

On iOS the app just bombs out with thread issue
I Have the project I can share
I thought it was zombies but nope.
have removed the shader from the object as well

Comment: can you be more specific and provide more information about the error that you are getting?

Comment: ok sooo their was a lot going on with this from incompatable movie file causing memory leaks, to incompatible versions of unity with plugin to unity having a bug. sorry I didn't come and close out been swamped on this project. - to Fix update everything....and re movie incompatable format i am still not 100% why this fails...